# Opening PDF in WPF with ActiveX

Tags: .net, wpf, pdf, activex

I'm a .NET developer; I need to open PDF files inside the user interface of my application. It's a standalone application (not a web application) running in Windows Vista; it's written in C# and uses WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) technology for the UI. I'd like to use an ActiveX control (which could already reside in my pc). I have **Adobe** ***Reader*** 8.0, but I seem to understand that **Adobe** ***Acrobat*** is required (see one of the answers at [Opening a pdf in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634769/opening-a-pdf-in-net)). Could anyone just confirm that Adobe Reader is not sufficient? This is, of course, the first point to clarify. If so: are there any **free** ActiveX controls that I could download? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is the Adobe Acrobat SDK, which is free to download [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html).

That contains classes such as AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF which you can access as shown in the discussion link you mentioned.

I'm afraid I haven't used it myself, so I don't know what requirements there would be on the user, but hopefully that could point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much, Stephen; I'm going to try (whithin a couple of days) it and I'll tell you things have gone!