# Can't open PDF, is there a way to detect if it opens?

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm writing a C# Windows program. On a form, I have a list of websites and PDFs. When they click on a PDF, the code downloads that file, then tries to open it. On my Windows 8 machine, the PDFs open fine. On Windows 7 and XP machines, they are not opening and there are no visual clues showing where things are breaking. (On both of these machines, you can click on a PDF in the file explorer and the PDFs will open.)

I started by looking at [Opening a pdf in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634769/opening-a-pdf-in-net), then added to that. Here's what I' using...

```
if (File.Exists(localFileName))
{
    //MessageBox.Show("calling file " + localFileName, "FYI...");
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "call /c " + localFileName;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    try
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("calling file " + localFileName, "FYI...");
        if (!process.Start())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not invoke the PDF Viewer. Try opening the file at " + localFileName, 
                "Problem Opening File...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't start process (call " + localFileName + "), Message=" + exc.Message, 
        "Problem Encounter...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    //MessageBox.Show("Should be done", "FYI...");
}
```

I am trying to detect whether the process starts or not. If I can't get them to execute, it would help if I could display a message telling the user where to look to open the downloaded file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally wrong. There is absolutely no need for `cmd.exe` to be involved in this operation, nor is there a need for `call /c` (and there's *absolutely* no need to require elevation as your answer suggests).

```
if FileExists(localFileName) {
    try
    { 
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(localFileName); 
    catch
    }
      /* 
         Handle failure to start process (Win32Exception)
         No need to handle FileNotFoundException, because
         you can do that in the else below
      */
    };
}
else
{
  // Handle missing file
}
```

`cmd.exe` is not needed, as it opens a new instance of the Windows command processor (AKA a command prompt), and `call /c` is only needed when `CALL`ing another batch file from within a batch file. There is certainly no need to elevate the process as your answer suggests.

Comment: VS is telling me that `!System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(localFileName)` is in error, Operator (!) cannot be applied to operand of type 'System.Diagnostic.Process'.

Comment: Yep, you're correct. The syntax I used is for the overload of `Start` that accepts no parameters. Corrected.

Comment: Right, without arguments it returns a bool, with arguments it returns a Process. I just tried `Process.Start(localFileName);` and it worked on the XP machine. I'll wrap it in the `try`, though, too. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be permission-related. I added `process.Verb = "runas"` to bump it up to admin level and it worked on the Windows 7 machine. On the XP machine, it prompted for an admin password, which isn't great but should be good enough for my purposes...

Comment: This is the wrong answer (even if it's acceptable to you, it's incorrect and bad information to provide to others as a solution to the problem).